# Display Images based on count ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview, dynamic

This should be an easy one - but difficult for a newbie like me.
I have a user-inputted count `n` - based on this, app should display `n` images in a grid. Use case: pass/fail system - `n` number of tests given, display red/green icons to denote pass fail for `n` tests, in sequential order, in one row.

For example:

```
Row 1: Class 1 | Tests given: 4 | * * o *

Row 2: Class 2 | Tests given: 8 | * * * * o o * * 

where * = image 1 (red), and o = image 2 (green)
```

Comment: What is exactly your question? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

Create a table.  Within the table create a repeater for the rows, source the data with classes.  Within each row, create another repeater.  In that repeater, source it by the class test results.  Set each td's class to be pass or fail.  In your CSS, set the background image to your desired image for pass/fail.

If you would like help with the code, please try to structure out something (whether it be similar to the above approach or not), and I would be happy to help you work through any stumbling blocks.